# Prove that $x_{n}$ identified by : with all $n\in \mathbb{N}, x_{n}= Sup(u_{n},v_{n})$ converges.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $u_{n},v_{n}$ are real serial numbers and converge. Prove that $x_{n}, y_{n}$ identified by : with all $n\in \mathbb{N}, \left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{n}= &Sup(u_{n},v_{n}) \\ 
y_{n}= &Inf(u_{n},v_{n}) 
\end{matrix}\right.$ converge.

---

I firstly approach to this field, so there are many thing make me confused. Please help me. Thank you so much!
Firstly, let $u_{n},v_{n}$ converge to $a,b$ respectively, and $b<a$. We solve for $x_{n}$.

I think with $n, N\in \mathbb{N}$ then we can choose $u_{N},v_{N}$ satisfying: $Sup(u_{N},v_{N})=\frac{1}{2}(u_{N}+v_{N}+|u_{N}-v_{N}|)$

- However I wonder that if we can only choose $u_{N}$ from an interval, does $x_{N}=Sup(u_{N},v_{N})$ exist?
- Another problem is that if the question above is solved, can I perform my solution as this or I need to find exactly $\varepsilon$ is?:

"$\forall \varepsilon >0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, (n\geq N\Rightarrow |x_{n}-x_{N}|\leq \varepsilon )$"

- In case we need to find $lim x_{n}$, then will $a$ be $lim x_{n}$?

Comment: The formula you have used to calculate the supremum is wrong. It should be: $\sup(u_{N},v_{N})=\frac{1}{2}(u_{N}+v_{N}+|u_{N}-v_{N}|)$

Comment: @Philipp Thank you

Comment: Does $\sup(u_n,v_n)$ mean that you are looking for the supremum of the open interval $(u_n,v_n)$ or is it simply the greatest number of the two values $v_n$ and $u_n$?

Comment: @Philipp I mean when the supremum exists in the each interval $(m,n)\subset(u_{n},v_{n})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding you first question:

As we are considering the real numbers we can make use of the *supremum axiom* which states that every bounded set of real numbers has a unique supremum. Both sequences $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are convergent and hence bounded so $x_n=\sup(u_n,v_n)$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I would solve the question as follows:

Let be $\epsilon:=a-b>0$ then due to convergence of $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ I can find two indices $N_u$ and $N_v$ such that for all members of $(u_n)$ with $n> N_u$ it holds that $|u_n-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and for all members of $(v_n)$ with $n> N_v$ it holds that $|v_n-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let be $N:=\max\{N_u,N_v\}$ then for all $n>N$ we see that  $u_n$ and $v_n$ satisfy $u_n<b+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=a-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<v_n$. So we can conclude that the supremum $x_n=\sup(u_n,v_n)$ exists as $(u_n,v_n)$ is bounded for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Furhter, it is always a member of the sequence $(v_n)$ or more precisely $x_n= v_n$ for all $n>N$. As the sequence $v_n$ converges it follows that the sequence $(x_n)$ converges as well.

The case where you consider the sequence $(y_n)$ is handled in the same way - just replace the $\sup$ with the $\inf$.

Answer (score 1):

I split up the proof for $(x_n)$ converges into 2 cases. One where $a=b$ and the other where $a \neq b$.

### Suppose $a=b$

Choose some $\epsilon >0.$

Then we know that $\exists N_1,N_2$ s.t. $\forall n>N_1 , m>N_2,$

$$
\vert u_n-a\vert < \epsilon \quad \textrm{and} \quad \vert v_m -b\vert < \epsilon.
$$

Let $M = max\{N_1 , N_2\}.$ Then, $\forall q > M,$

$$\tag{1}
\vert u_q-a\vert < \epsilon \quad \textrm{and} \quad \vert v_q -b\vert < \epsilon.
$$

Therefore, $(1)$ holds for $sup(u_q,v_q)$. Thus, $(x_n)$ converges.

### Suppose $a \neq b$

Wlog, assume $b<a$ and let $\epsilon >0.$

Then we know that $\exists N_1,N_2$ s.t. $\forall n>N_1 , m>N_2,$

$$\tag{2}
\vert u_n-a\vert < \epsilon \quad \textrm{and} \quad \vert v_m -b\vert < \epsilon.
$$

Let $M = max\{N_1 , N_2 \}$ and let $0<\epsilon < \frac{a-b}{3}$.

Then, using the above and $(2)$ we get $\forall q > M$

$$
\vert u_q-a\vert < \epsilon < \frac{a-b}{3}  \quad \textrm{and} \quad \vert v_q -b\vert < \epsilon < \frac{a-b}{3}
$$

Which implies, $x_q = sup(u_q,v_q) = u_q$ $\tag{3}$

Thus, $(x_n)$ converges to $a$.

$Q.E.D.$

Where $(3)$ holds as $b<a$ and we are now only considering the intervals $\big[b - \frac{a-b}{3},b+ \frac{a-b}{3}\big], \big[a- \frac{a-b}{3},a +\frac{a-b}{3} \big]$. Consider drawing a diagram if you don't seem to follow.

The proof for $(y_n)$ is similar to the proof above but uses $inf$.

Comment: Can you explain more about  $ |u_{q}-a|<\epsilon <\frac{a-b}{3}$ and $|v_{q}-a|<\epsilon <\frac{a-b}{3}$ can implies $(3)$ for me?

Comment: @AnhTuấnTrầnNguyễn, it's basically the same I argument I have used. If you write out $$\vert u_q-a\vert<\epsilon<\frac{a-b}{3}\textrm{ and }\vert v_q -b\vert<\epsilon<\frac{a-b}{3},$$you will get$$a-\epsilon<u_q<a+\epsilon\textrm{ and }b-\epsilon<v_q<b+\epsilon.$$As $b+\epsilon<b+\frac{a-b}{3}<a-\epsilon$ we can see that for all members of the two sequences which have an index $q>M$ it holds $v_q<u_q$. So the supremum must be $u_q$. In this context it makes more sense to write $x_q=\sup(v_q,u_q)=u_q$ because the right end of the intervall end will always be a member from the sequence $u_n$

Comment: @Philipp explained it quite well.

Essentially, having 
$$\vert u_q - a \vert < \epsilon \; and \; \vert v_q - b \vert < \epsilon$$

implies that  $ \forall q >M, u_q \in [a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]$ and $v_q \in [b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]$.


As $0<\epsilon<\frac{a-b}{3}$ we get $b+\epsilon < a-\epsilon.$ 

Thus, $\forall q >M, v_q<u_q.$ Therefore, $x_q = sup(v_q,u_q) = u_q.$ As we know $u_q$ converges, this implies $x_q$ converges to the same limit.